# Visual Studio 2019 Code-Formatter "Ctrl+K / Ctrl +D" Mess up the HTML Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

For some unknown reason when I use <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>. `vs2019` turns my code like below:

[image]

It automatically add breaks after inline css and remove any space from texts. I have no clue how to fix this issue which happened after I installed vs2019.

Comment: VS has had a long time problem with Razor code when formatting. Putting braces on their own line seems to make this even worse :-(. (One True Brace Style and it is not so bad, this might be a not completely subjective observation. And I also know that is an enormous can of worms.)

Comment: @Richard Indeed... however the code works but it doesn't feel so good..

Comment: Send feedback through VS and the product team will follow up with you to try and reproduce.  I don't think this one is a known issue.

Comment: @Jimmy how may i be able to do this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Jimmy they fixed the issue pending for release ;)